# SPI slave is sending one byte twice at a very specific time in data packet and causes corruption of the whole data packet

Tags: microcontroller, spi, communication, interrupts

I am trying to communicate with a display device (master) which sends two type of data packets with 50 kHz clock. One data packet is 16 bytes and one is 32 bytes long. The data format is as follows:

[image]

Now for read command, my response bytes should be during the dummy bytes that the display device is sending.

Here is the snippet of code in ISR where I have implemented a state machine to respond to data bytes:

```cpp
void spiIsr(const tsDevCom *device) {
  tsSpiParams *params = device->parameters;
  const tsSpiConsts *consts = device->constants;
  tsDevComSystem *sys = device->sys;
  static uint8_t txBuffer[] = {0x20, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};    
  static uint8_t command = 0;
  static uint8_t length = 0;
  static uint8_t adress = 0; 
  static uint8_t index = 0;
  static uint8_t crc= 0x8b;

  if (SH_SET == SPI_GetINTStatus(consts->SPIx, SPI_FUNC_RECEIVE)) {
    uint8_t temp = (uint8_t)SPI_ReceiveData(consts->SPIx);

    switch (params->eSPIState) {     
    case _SPIState_Start:
      if (temp == 0xAA) {
        params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Command;
        SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 1); // 1
        index = 0;
      }
      else
        SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 0); // 0
      break;

    case _SPIState_Command:
      command = temp;
      params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Adress; 
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 2); //2
      break;
        
    case _SPIState_Adress:
      adress = temp;
      params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Size;
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 3); // Response in Adress state 
      break;

    case _SPIState_Size:
      length = temp;
      if (command == 0x02) {
        params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Command_RX_Data;
        SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 10);}
      else {
        params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Command_TX_Data;
        SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, txBuffer[index]);
      }
      index++;
      break;

    case _SPIState_Command_RX_Data:
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, txBuffer[index]);
      index++;
      if (index>=length)
        params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Command_RX_Checksum;
      break;

    case _SPIState_Command_TX_Data:
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, txBuffer[index]);
      index++;
      if (index>=length)
        params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Command_TX_Checksum;
      break;

    case _SPIState_Command_RX_Checksum:
      params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Start;
      index= 0;
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 0x55);
      break;

    case _SPIState_Command_TX_Checksum:
      params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Start;
      index= 0;
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, crc);
      break;

    default:
      params->eSPIState = _SPIState_Start;
      SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 0x89);
      index= 0;
    }

    SPI_ClearINTStatus(consts->SPIx, SPI_FUNC_RECEIVE);   
  }
}
```

Here are the pictures of response bytes for both data packets:

[image]

[image]

Now in both packets we can see that 0x03 on MISO is seen twice, even though it should be once, and then the first byte of Txbuffer.

When I try to debug and put break point at this line

```cpp
SPI_SendData(consts->SPIx, 3);  // Response in Address state
```

then it captures everything correctly.

Why is it happening at this specific place and how it can it be solved?

The microcontroller I am using is from Sinowealth and I am not using the SS pin at the slave side.

Is there any better way to do it? Because I think doing that much stuff in an ISR is never recommended. So what other option should I use in this scenario?

Comment: Are you sure that "SPI_enable" should be released between the bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You made great progress in this project. Cooking each byte to send directly after having received one is a good solution.

I assume the response time of your code is at the boundary. I guess from the screen shot that you have only around 10..20 µs time to transfer the byte to send to the SPI transmit buffer.

This works most of the time, but in the _SPIState_Size case you have one additional if condition and an indexed array access. So the code execution may just need some more time and the transfer comes too late. In this situation the SPI hardware repeats the last content of the TX register.

You can precalculate the byte to send in the previous case statement right after the SPI_SendDate call, where you have time. So you can avoid the array access, which may help to improve the response time.

Sinowealth MCUs seam to be 24 MHz 8051 systems, there is not much margin to solve this task using high language code.

Comment: Thanks @Jens for your valuable response. But I have already tested this by skipping the if statement and replacing array with a number. It still behave similarly. One thing is, you can see the master is configured in mode 0 but when I configure my board in SPI mode 0, it echo back on MISO what receive from MOSI. But works like this when I choose Mode 3. Is there a chance that mode has something to do with this?

Comment: I recommend to use a spare I/O bit, set it at the start of the ISR routine and clear it on the exit. With this bit connected to a channel of the analyser you can see the response time of the code. I am not familiar with Sinowealth MCUs, but I don't think that the SPI mode produces this kind of error. There may be other system interrupts, that can delay the response of this ISR.